# Login Form using sql database c#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, authentication, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to make a sign up page . you put user name and password and its save in the sql database.

note: evrey thing worked until i add the 2nd column(the password).

this is the password code(the username is the same) :

```
    static public void delete(string _Password)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES(@Password)", connection);
            commandInsert.Parameters.Add("Password", _Password);
            commandInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlCeException expection)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(expection.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

And this is the button settings :

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (deleteBox.Text != "")
                {
                    SQLFunctions.Insert(insertBox.Text);
                    SQLFunctions.delete(deleteBox.Text);
                    SQLFunctions.Refresh(this.dataGridView1);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("login failed");
                }
            }
```

**thanks**

Comment: What is the error? Also, when you say u `Insert`, does your table just have `Password` as a column? Provide us the table structure.

Comment: Why is the function called delete when it does an insert?

Comment: You are inserting the username into one row, and the password into another.  There's nothing linking them together.

Comment: You should look into [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx).  Also you shouldn't make methods so blatantly misleading

Comment: In addition to what others have said: if the code for Username is the same, this surely won't work since you have "INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES(@Password)" but the order of the fields will cause this to likely insert Password into the Username field.  You should specify the fields you want to insert to in your SQL query.

Comment: this is the table https://www.dropbox.com/s/etln1l179v5yuo1/1.PNG?dl=0 this is the error https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlsi8d4dbb1qpsq/errori.PNG?dl=0 and this is the form https://www.dropbox.com/s/qf8strsexig3wy7/form1.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to modify your code little bit like this

```
SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES(@username,@Password)", connection);
```

you should pass two parameters as you have two fields in db now and if you don't want to pass username then you should specify this thing like this

```
SqlCeCommand commandInsert = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO [Table](password) VALUES(@Password)", connection);
```

and also

```
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("Password", _Password);
```

this should be written as follows

```
commandInsert.Parameters.Add("@Password", _Password);
```

and to pass values to this parameter, you can do it like this

```
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", insertBox.Text);
```